# The dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been communicating with my professor on this following problem since this morning but I made little headway on my part:

> If $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ (here $n \geqslant 3$) which consists of vectors $V = (v_1, v_2, \ldots , v_n)$ with $v_1 = v_2 = v_3$, then find the dimension of $S$.

Here are what I have gathered so far: The $S$ will be consisting of vectors the like of $(v_1,v_1,v_1, v_4, \ldots, v_n)$, $(v_2,v_2,v_2, v_4, \ldots, v_n)$ or $(v_3,v_3,v_3, v_4, \ldots, v_n)$, etc. And then I was told to come up with a linear mapping $L\colon \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ where the $\ker (L)$ will be the subspace $S$, with the final answer will be $n-2$.

But unfortunately even after all of these, I was not able to connect all of these dots. Please help me therefore in terms of elementary linear algebra since I am totally new in this craft of proofs. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense your definition of $\;V\;$: a subspace of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is either the zero subspace or it is **infinite**, so what  *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: I think they meant that $S$ is the subspace spanned by the vectors in $V$.

Comment: Hint:  Prove that $V$ is spanned by $\vec {e_1}+\vec {e_2}+\vec {e_3}$ and $\{\vec {e_i}\}_{i=4}^n$.

Comment: @DonAntonio : I suspect that the incredibly poorly written quoted text, in the context of the instructor's mapping hint, should read "Let $n \geq 3$ and $S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_1 = x_2 = x_3 \}$. Find the dimension of $S$."

Comment: @EricTowers I think you may be right. Hard to believe students in college/university have so poor writing skills... Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio : It's possible that a student wrote the quoted text.  It may have been paraphrased or approximately transcribed by a student.  It seems more likely that it is copied from an instructor's writing or from a textbook, both of which are far worse.

Comment: @EricTowers Whatever. I'd expect a university student to proof-read anything he handles, evenmore if he's asking a question. Copying from someone or something else is not an excuse at all, imo, to write in such a poor way.

Comment: Honestly I copied the problem the way it was given to me. I had to communicate with the prof back and forth because it was confusing to me. At the end of days, though, I respect all your opinions. I will take all the blames since I am the one who posted it.

Comment: @DonAntonio : It is irrational to expect a non-expert to correct a purported expert's poor writing.  If a student were facile enough with the material to do so, the student is in the wrong class.  Further, you will never see such a student post such a question on StackExchange due to obvious selection bias.  Such a student would point out to the instructor that the instructor has written gibberish and not waste anyone's time on the gibberish version.

Answer (score 2):

Every element of $S$ is written in the form:

$$(v_1,v_1,v_1,v_4,\ldots,v_n)=v_1(1,1,1,0,0,\ldots,0)+v_4(0,0,0,1,0,\ldots,0)+\ldots+v_n(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots,0,1)$$
and therefore $S$ is the linear span of the $n-2$ vectors $$(1,1,1,0,0,\ldots,0),~(0,0,0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots,~(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots,0,1).$$You may easily check that these vectors are linearly independent, and therefore they are a basis for subspace $S.$ Since the dimension of $S$ is the cardinality of a basis of $S$, the dimension of $S$ is $n-2.$

Comment: Thank you! You gave me an elementary alternative to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice is 
$$(v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n)\mapsto (v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1) $$

Comment: Yes! I was also told to proceed along that way. Is there anyway for you to elaborate. I am totally lost, honestly.

Comment: $v_2-v_1=0$ and $v_3-v_1=0$ are precisely the equations that we expect to hold for vectors in $S$

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$L:(\nu_1,\nu_2,\nu_3, \dots, \nu_n) \to (\nu_1-\nu_2,\nu_1-\nu_3)$.

Comment: I was told the same, but why? I don't want just to copy it down blindly.

Comment: What is the kernel of this map?

Comment: $(\nu_1-\nu_2,\nu_1-\nu_3)=(0,0)$

Comment: Can you tell me why I have to find the kernel, please. I am afraid this is a dumb question. Thanks.

Comment: The Dimension Theorem! $\dim(image(L)) + \dim(\ker(L)) = \dim(\mathbb{R}^n)$. That gives us $2 + (n-2) = n$.

Comment: Another dumb question: So the answer to the problem comes from the $dim(Ker(L))$, or from $dim(Im(L))$?

Comment: In this case, $S$ is the kernel, with $\dim S= n-2$, but you can use this theorem either way, depending on your map.

Comment: Thank you for taking time answering my questions. I gave you 3 up-votes.